# Reverse PDF imposition

Tags: python, linux, pdf-generation, pdftk, imposition

I have an imposed document: there are `4 × n` A4 pages on the `n` sheets. I put them into a roller image scanner and receive one `2 × n` paged PDF document (A3).

If, say, `n = 3`, then I've got the following sequence of A3 pages in my PDF:

- page one: page `12` (on the left) and page `1` of the original document
- page two: p.`2` and p.`11` of the original document
- page three: p.`10` and p.`3`…
- … and so on until…
- page six: p.`6` and p.`7` of the original document

Question: how can I reconstruct the original sequence of pages in one PDF file of the A4 format? I.e. I want to do this:

```
--A3--         --A4--
[12| 1]         [1]
[ 2|11]         [2]
[10| 3]    ⇒    [3]
   …             … 
[ 6| 7]         [6]
                [7]
                 … 
                [12]
```

In linux I usually use `pdftk` or `pdftops`-like console utilities for this kind of cases, but I cannot figure out how to use them for my current purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf/179398) and tuned the code a bit:

```
import copy
import sys
import math
import pyPdf

def split_pages(src, dst):
    src_f = file(src, 'r+b')
    dst_f = file(dst, 'w+b')

    input_PDF = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(src_f)
    num_pages = input_PDF.getNumPages()

    first_half, second_half = [], []

    for i in range(num_pages):
        p = input_PDF.getPage(i)
        q = copy.copy(p)
        q.mediaBox = copy.copy(p.mediaBox)

        x1, x2 = p.mediaBox.lowerLeft
        x3, x4 = p.mediaBox.upperRight

        x1, x2 = math.floor(x1), math.floor(x2)
        x3, x4 = math.floor(x3), math.floor(x4)
        x5, x6 = math.floor(x3/2), math.floor(x4/2)

        if x3 > x4:
            # horizontal
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x5, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x5, x2)
        else:
            # vertical
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x6)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x6)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)


        if i in range(1,num_pages+1,2):
            first_half += [p]
            second_half += [q]
        else:
            first_half += [q]
            second_half += [p]

    output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()
    for page in first_half + second_half[::-1]:
        output.addPage(page)

    output.write(dst_f)
    src_f.close()
    dst_f.close()

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("\nusage:\n$ python reverse_impose.py input.pdf output.pdf")
    sys.exit()

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

split_pages(input_file,output_file)
```

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kirienko/55436c7c68088a98ffe54a68c7bd7b4c).